# Java - InputStream - Test for input

Tags: java, inputstream, midp

I am sending data to a server in two steps:
1) Length of what I will send using byte[4]
2) Data.

The server listens to the exact length of the data (shipped first) and then replies.

So I listen to the InputStream and try to get the data.

**My Problem:**
Whatever I am doing I am getting only the stream I send, but the server definatly sends a new string.

It seems I cannot wait for a -1 (end of string), as the program would time out and I am sure the server does not send anything alike.

Therefore I am using inputStream.available() to find out how many bytes are left in the buffer.

Once I am sending inputStream.read() after reading all the data it will time out with "Network idle timeout".

But I need to listen to the inputStream to make sure I am not missing information.

Why am I only receiving the information I send and not what is send by the server?
How can I listen to the connection for new items coming in?

Here is my code:

```
    private void sendData (byte[] sendBytes){
        try {
            os.write(sendBytes);
            os.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
```

Please help
THD

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, but using is.available() is not correct. What is the server doing? What is the client doing? What type of server is it?

Comment: What I want to do:
receive data from the server.
The client sends out data, the server receives them (correct tested by the folks doing the serverside stuff).
The server sends data, but the client does not read the correct data, but it only reads the string the client send before, once the server sends something (differnt).
I have no clue what kind of server it is and I cannot ask the Server guys before Monday.

Comment: I can see the data I receive in:
inputStream.parent.Inherited.buf.0-99
iStreams is set to 1, connectionOpen is true
Anything else that I can post, that would help?

Comment: Yes, describe what the data from the server looks like. Will the server send data, and keep the connection open, or will it close the connection after it has sent data? Will it also send a data length before it sends data? Is there a protocol that you are using?

Comment: Ok, that means that the server sends data according to a certain protocol, even if it is a simle one. What does the protocol look like?

Comment: I send the following string: INIT?IMEI=XXX (plus a byte 0 to let the server know that thats it)
The server sends "OK?Mui=15" (nothing else and keeps the connection open)

Comment: ... but how will you know that you have received all data from the server? Does it send data length first? Does the replies have fixed width, or delimiters?

Comment: Nothing yet. currently I am reading data one by one, but the result is not what is send. Available actually gives me at the moment 'a' length. But my first concern is, that I am only rereading the data I send, although I read it from the inputStream. How can that be, and how can I change it?

Comment: Hard to say since we haven't seend your full source code. You should never see your own data unless the server sends it back, unless you have done something very dodgy.

Comment: Is there a way to post more code? I could edit my post, if you think it is helpful?

Comment: Yes, edit your question.

Comment: Edited. Now you can see the full code (just stripped some exceptions)

Comment: That code doesn't look correct, you are e.g. throwing away the first byte from the server, but I still need more information in order to help you solve your problem. How does the server separate messages? Does it write a length? Is there a message delimiter?

Comment: There is no real time communication. The client always sends first and waits for an answer. So whatever comes after the clinet send something, is one message. (I know that currently the first byte is lost, but this more about getting a first message)

Comment: That isn't something that will work. The client will never be able to tell if he has received a complete message unless the server either sends a length, uses fixed width data, or uses a separator between each message.

Comment: Got it working.
I am using InputStream.available() and it read how many bytes are still not read. That way I know how many characters per message are send. And it works quite well.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry to say, it might look like it is working, but what you have implemented is error prone on slow networks. There's nothing that says that the data that the server writes will arrive at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you normally read all data from a reader (until the other end closes):

```
//BufferedReader is 
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
char[] buffer = new char[1024 * 32];
int len = 0;
while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    data.append(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

`//data will on this line contain all code received from the server`

Comment: StringBuilder is not available in my Java. I substituted it with StringBuffer. is.read(buffer) is not available. And at the end, waiting for -1 gets me a timeout.

Comment: Your Java? What are you writing?

Comment: I added that tag to your question, since that is very relevant to know.